# Passing Unicode strings to terminal from Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I'm running [this assistive technology project](http://theopenvoicefactory.org).

It includes the following Perl script that creates a wav from text using eSpeak. (The browser then plays the file for the user)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
    use warnings;
use CGI qw(:standard -debug);
my $text = param('text');
my $filename = param('filename');
die if $text =~ /\x00/;
die if $filename =~ /\x00/;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
$text =~ s/^-+//;
system('/home/joereddington/tts/espeak-1.48.04-source/src/speak', $text, '-w', $filename .  '.wav', '-v', 'en');
```

This works fine for English, but on the bulgarian and arabic language versions, I just get "Hashtag 0392, Hashtag 0929,..." over and over again.  I'm assuming that's because at some point in the process, the unicode for those character sets is getting butchered.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Does running `/home/joereddington/tts/espeak-1.48.04-source/src/speak` in the terminal with a bulgarian word work?

Comment: You can add debug-output by adding `use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';` at the top, and `die $text` at after the `my $text` line. Then run it in your browser. It will tell you what it saw.

Comment: Your CGI script allows remote command execution. You should quote `$text` and `$filename` before passing it to the shell.